# EPS plot to LaTeX with special characters

Tags: graphics, characters, eps, epstopdf

I'm trying to put an EPS plot made with SigmaPlot. The axis titles have some portuguese characters, like "ç" or "ã", and maybe equations.

When I put the plot into LaTeX I'm not getting the special characters. Here are my code, 2 plots that I made trying a good image, and the results.

There's a way to get "Remoção" in the y-axis??

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf} %Para importar os graficos feitos em GraphPad

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \subfloat[With no text modification]{
            \includegraphics{EPS1}
        }
        \subfloat[With  text modification]{
            \includegraphics{EPS2}
        }
        \caption{Figures with text problems}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are the plot files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6XiD7MJaw4mRDFiUTd3SHVKYW8?usp=sharing

Comment: The .eps file itself doesn't have these characters with diacritics. Probably Sigma Plot uses LaTeX for the labels, and doesn't load the required packages. You can try to replace the labels with `psfrag`.

Comment: The issue is SigmaPlot (which generated the EPS files) and not in LaTeX. Try opening the EPS file in some other viewer to see this. LaTeX `\includgraphics` simply passes the file through as it is, mostly. And `epstopdf` calls that script to convert to pdf. (The encoding in your PS file is just Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) though, so it may be possible in principle for the EPS-to-PDF converter to work around this…)

Comment: I use SigmaPlot to output PDF's.  I then use Acrobat to crop the PDFs and finally use pdflatex to `\includegraphics` those directly into the document.  It works great that way.  Of course, I may not have triggered the special-character issue that you have...

Comment: @Bernard It has (lines 555 and 561 in `eps1.eps`), it is ISO 8859-1 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `epstopdf` did not embed needed fonts: `Times-Italic` and `Times-Roman`: [image].

Additional comment: EPS files you provided are ISO 8859-1 encoded, that might be the issue as well.

Can you share the details about your TeX-system, `epstopdf` version, do you have `times` package installed etc.?